# Get paragraph on same line as header in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML and CSS code which I've taken from a WordPress theme.

```
<div class="ws-contact-info">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h2 style="text-align: center;">Phone:</h2>
            <p style="text-align: center;"><a href="#">(098) 765-4321</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

On a webpage it presents as follows
[image]

```
Phone:
(098) 765-4321
```

How can I write my CSS to make the elements fit into one row, like this:

```
Phone: (098) 765-4321
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply `display: inline-block` to the `<h2>` and `<p>` elements, as they are both `block` elements, so they are taking up the whole width, causing the line break.

Alternatively, you could apply `float: left` to both of them.